# Can python be installed wrong, and result in unexpected errors?

Tags: python-3.x, class, arguments, typeerror

I'm new to programming. I downloaded python 3.11.2 and started coding with pycharm. But when I tried to make a class and add arguments, unexpected error was raised.
The code is quite simple:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name):
        print(name)


example = Item("example_2")
```

The output was:

```
TypeError: Item() takes no arguments
```

And when I add an argument:

```
class Item(*args):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print(name)
# or any other argument

example = Item("example_2")
```

An error is raised:

```
NameError: name 'args' is not defined
```

I'm confident the code is all correct, for I copied it from a tutorial.
I tried reinstalling python and pycharm.
I don't have another device to test the issue on.

assuming I'm telling the truth, do you have any idea what could be the cause, or perhaps how to fix it? Thanks.